# notify user in android application when inserting new record by website

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android project that connected with website using php and MySql DB
I want to notify the user that has the application when the admin insert new record by the website.
I'm searching for solutions, and I found this one
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html
but I didn't Know, is it the suitable solution for me? 
or there are another solutions
thanks

Comment: I believe is the easiest way to push notification on an Android devices

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a fine way to notify your app - you'll just have to add in the code on the website to call gcm when the data changes.

Another solution would be to have your app periodically poll the website for changes, but that's costly in terms of bandwidth.  I'd use GCM

Comment: Thanks for advising, I will use GCM :)